# Where are the azure function logs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Ok stupid question,
I created an azure function that uses logs. The application insights are not activated, so no logs, but I have activated the diagnostic settings to route them to a storage account.

Here is the stupid question, where are the logs stored in the storage account?

Answer (score 1):

> The application insights are not activated, so no logs

You need to activate or on or create application insights for azure functions to store logs.

One way of creating is while creating function app as below:

[image]

The other way is after creating a function inside function app as below:

[image]

Another way:

[image]

Only if you configure or on Application insights logs will be stored and then after configuring then again run your function app:

[image]

Then wait for 5 min, then logs will be appearing these sections of function app:

[image]

And you can also check in Logs section as below:

[image]

Now you can set diagnostic settings and send to Log Analytics (which I use and suggest)  and then these logs will go to Log analytics and you check using `FunctionAppLogs`  query in logs section. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp)

As you said you used stoarge account:

You can check logs in containers section as below:

[image]