# Application Insights get raw text

Tags: azure-application-insights

When I run a query with KQL on Application Insights (from the portal).
Say

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| summarize Count=count() by type
| sort by Count desc
| take 5
| join kind=inner (
   exceptions
   | where timestamp > ago(24h)
) on type
```

I get a bunch of columns. Is there any function/query or format that I can apply to get the raw text. I just need the raw text of each item in the result. So I can copy and query the text. Maybe I'm old school but I don't like the Application Insights column view ;)

exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| summarize Count=count() by type
| sort by Count desc
| take 5
| join kind=inner (
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
) on type

Comment: what do you mean by raw text? This query will return only the raw text of each item in the result set. If you want to copy and query the text, you can simply copy and paste the result set into a new query.

Comment: You can use the `project` keyword to extract certain data eg ```exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(24h)
| summarize Count=count() by type
| sort by Count desc
| take 5
| join kind=inner (
   exceptions
   | where timestamp > ago(24h)
) on type
| project problemId```

Which will give you just the problemId column. But it's not clear what you mean by "raw text".

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with @Jason Evans, that if you are using Azure Application insights, you will get logs in a table format like below:

[image]

If you want individual column you can use below query:

```
exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| summarize Count=count() by type
| sort by Count desc
| take 5
| join kind=inner (
   exceptions
   | where timestamp > ago(30d)
) on type
| project method
```

[image]

Here I am using `project` to get required column.
`Kql` is Kusto query language which gets information in table format so raw text is not possible to get.
If you want logs in a file then you can export the logs to storage account like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76411430/17623802) and then you will get a log file.